# Ring Homomorphism determined by a 6th root of unity

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, complex-numbers, ring-homomorphism

I am working on the following problem :

Let $K$ denote the algebraic closure of the 5 element field $F_5$. Let $f: F_5[x] \longrightarrow K$ be the ring homomorphism determined by $f(x) = \omega$, where $\omega$ is a primitive 6th root of 1 in $K$.

a) What is $f(3x^{50} - 2x^{45} +2)$ ?

b) Find the dimension, over $F_5$, of the image of $f$.

c) Find the kernel of $f$.

I think I've got a good grasp on part a). We use basic properties that any ring homomorphism satisfies:

$f(3x^{50} - 2x^{45} + 2) = f(3x^{50}) - f(2x^{45}) + f(2)$

= $3[f(x)]^{50} - 2[f(x)]^{45} + f(2)$

= $3(\omega^{50}) - 2(\omega^{45}) + f(2)$

= $3(\omega^2) - 2(\omega^3) + f(2)$   (using that $\omega^6 = 1$)

= $3 \cdot \omega^2 - 2 \cdot \omega^3$

My only question here is, am I justified in saying $f(2) = 0$, since the homomorphism is determined completely by $f(x) = \omega$ ?

b) I'm not sure about this part. I thought of using the rank-nullity theorem, but since $F_5[x]$ is not finite-dimensional, I don't know of a clever way to use this to determine the dimension of the image. Is there some other way here to determine the dimension of the image?

c) I know of the identity $1 + \omega + \omega^2 + ... + \omega^{n-1} = 0$, where $\omega$ is an nth root of unity. But, how can I take $f$ of an element in $F_5[x]$ and obtain $1 + \omega + ... + \omega^5$, if I don't know what $f(1)$ is ? I can only deduce what $f(0)$ is, since a ring homomorphism sends identity elements to identity elements. Also, after, if possible, I can find what element in $F_5[x]$ gets sent to $1 + \omega + ... + \omega^5 = 0$, is there any other element of $F_5[x]$ that can get send to $0$ by $f$, besides $0$ ? Or is the kernel only consisting of $0$ and the element mapping to $1 + \omega + .. + \omega^5$?

Thanks!

Comment: $f(2)=2$, because the prime field must map to itself. Why do dyou think it is $0$?

Comment: 2. Because $x$ is mapped to a root of $x^6-1$, the map factors through $F[x]/(x^6-1)$, which *is* finite dimensional. 3. Well, $1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^5$ looks to me like it maps to $1+\omega^2+\cdots+\omega^5$....

Comment: Because $\omega^{5^2} = \omega$ the minimal polynomial of $\omega$ is $(x-\omega)(x-\omega^5)=x^2-x+1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be a little confused when it comes to what $f$ does. $f$ does not send any element of $\mathbb{F}_5$ to $0$. What $f$ does, is take a polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_5[X]$ and *evaluate* that polynomial in $\omega$.

---

The first thing to do when you solve this kind of exercise, is to find the minimal polynomial of $\omega$ over $\mathbb{F}_5$. Since $\omega$ is a primitive $6$'th root, this must be the sixth [Cyclotomic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial), $x^2-x+1$.

From the fact that the degree of this minimal polynomial is $2$, we may conclude that the powers of $\omega$ can be written as linear combinations of $1$ and $\omega$. Since $\omega\not\in\mathbb{F}_5$, these two are clearly linearly independent and the dimension of $\operatorname{im}f=\mathbb{F}_5(\omega)$ as a vectorspace over $\mathbb{F}_5$ is $2$. (In general, for algebraic field extensions $K\subset K(\alpha)$, the dimension of $K(\alpha)$ as a vectorspace over $K$ is the degree of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $K$)

The kernel of $f$ are all polynomials which are zero when evaluated in $f$, so all a polynomials with $\omega$ as a root. These are precisely the polynomials divisible by the minimal polynomial of $\omega$, so
$$\ker f = (x^2-x+1),$$
the principal ideal generated by $x^2-x+1$.